# After 16.04.1 update iphone access limited

Tags: 16.04, iphone

I just updated to the new Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Since the update, the access to the iphone(3GS, ios6) is limited.

Before the update I could access all needed data on the iphone.

There were two drives available to access: One was called just **"Iphone"** and the was other called **"Documents on Iphone"**.

The **"Iphone"** Drive gave access to photos, Videos and other files and the **"Documents on Iphone"** gave access to the to the Data of installed Apps.

After the update it is only possible to access some Data of two installed Apps.

Any idea how to fix it?

I want access to the shoot images on the Phone.

Computer information:

> Acer Aspire One ZG5 Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz